# Error 503 Service Unavailable

Tags: debian, ssl, reverse-proxy, apache2, 503-error

We have a debian based reverse proxy server which is under testing for product scanning for a store and all of a sudden it didn't connect and started showing 503 service unavailable. The next day it was all back to normal. I need to figure out what actually caused the problem.

**ssl_error_ssl.log**

> [Mon Aug 29 16:46:41.591170 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 510018:tid 140359615092480
> ] (111)Connection refused: AH00957: https: attempt to connect to xxx.xx.xx.xxx:
> 443 (xxxxxxxxxxxx.com:443) failed

**ssl_access_ssl.log**

> [29/Aug/2022:16:38:23 +0200] "POST /scanless-frontend-service/res
> t/self-service-store/v1/itemTaken HTTP/1.1" 503 299 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.5.6
> (Java/1.8.0_281)"

The logs which above are rev proxy logs.

Attaching **error log**

> [Mon Aug 29 08:32:23.582826 2022] [core:notice] [pid 4766 64:tid
> 140359833754944] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
>
> [Tue Aug 30 00:00:07.852429 2022] [mpm_worker:notice] [pid 476664:tid
> 1403598337 54944] AH00297: SIGUSR1 received. Doing graceful restart

**syslog**

> Aug 29 16:47:08 itrevproxy02 systemd[1]: apt-daily.service: Succeeded.
>
> Aug 29 16:47:08 itrevproxy02 systemd[1]: Finished Daily apt download
> activities.
>
> Aug 29 17:17:01 itrevproxy02 CRON[510421]: (root) CMD ( cd / &&
> run-parts --re port /etc/cron.hourly)
>
> Aug 29 18:17:01 itrevproxy02 CRON[510439]: (root) CMD ( cd / &&
> run-parts --re port /etc/cron.hourly)
>
> Aug 29 19:13:43 itrevproxy02 falcon-sensor[257649]: CrowdStrike(4):
> SslConnect: lfodown01-lanner-lion.cloudsink.net:443
>
> Aug 29 19:13:43 itrevproxy02 falcon-sensor[257649]: CrowdStrike(4):
> ConnectWithP roxy: Unable to get application proxy host from CsConfig:
> c0000225
>
> Aug 29 19:13:43 itrevproxy02 falcon-sensor[257649]: CrowdStrike(4):
> SslConnect: Unable to connect to
> lfodown01-lanner-lion.cloudsink.net:59552 via Application P roxy:
> c0000225
>
> Aug 29 19:13:43 itrevproxy02 falcon-sensor[257649]: CrowdStrike(4):
> trying to co nnect to lfodown01-lanner-lion.cloudsink.net:443
>
> Aug 29 19:13:43 itrevproxy02 falcon-sensor[257649]: CrowdStrike(4):
> Connected di rectly to lfodown01-lanner-lion.cloudsink.net:443
>
> Aug 29 19:13:43 itrevproxy02 falcon-sensor[257649]: CrowdStrike(4):
> ValidateCert ificate: Certificate verified!
>
> Aug 29 19:13:43 itrevproxy02 falcon-sensor[257649]: CrowdStrike(4):
> SSLSocket co nnected successfully to
> lfodown01-lanner-lion.cloudsink.net:443
>
> Aug 29 19:17:01 itrevproxy02 CRON[510456]: (root) CMD ( cd / &&
> run-parts --re port /etc/cron.hourly)
>
> Aug 29 20:17:01 itrevproxy02 CRON[510473]: (root) CMD ( cd / &&
> run-parts --re port /etc/cron.hourly)
>
> Aug 29 21:17:01 itrevproxy02 CRON[510490]: (root) CMD ( cd / &&
> run-parts --re port /etc/cron.hourly) –

Can someone please help me understand what has caused this error?

Comment: `Connection refused: AH00957: https: attempt to connect to xxx.xx.xx.xxx: 443 (xxxxxxxxxxxx.com:443) failed`.  Your proxy couldn't connect to xxx.xx.xx.xxx:443 - maybe looking in the logs on that server would be a good start?  It seems the proxy is doing what it should.

Comment: Hi GarethTheRed ......I posted logs which i found in server....these were repeating so just added once.

Comment: Are they the reverse-proxy logs or the proxied server logs?

Comment: GarethTheRed.....added the logs in the link

Comment: There's nothing much in those logs around the time of the failure.  The only thing we can glean is that apt-daily was running at around the time the server issued the 503 response.  Other than the apt download service, we don't know what else was being run.  The server seems to be running Apache with MPM.  Are you running a PHP application or similar?  If so, find out where that logs to and inspect those.

Comment: no php application.....the problem was there untill late night and apt daily was running for sometime only i think. One of my colleague from network said he could see many logs which blocked the connection. If it has blocked then it should stay as it is but the server was back normal next day.

Comment: So Apache is only service static files, such as images or HTML pages?

Comment: Yes. Since it is just beginning not much have been added and the store is testing if everything goes well when someone pickup a product and scan it.

Comment: I suspect there are more logs somewhere.  The ones you currently show aren't much to go by.